# How to get a value from a Mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I just start learning Mongodb and pymongo. I intended to extend a new list to a list value of a document, I've tried find() but nothing come out.. Following is my data structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c478b"), "ip" : "61.228.93.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-11T20:29:51" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c478c"), "ip" : "61.231.1.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-15T15:54:17" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c478d"), "ip" : "220.135.220.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-11T08:42:41" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c478e"), "ip" : "111.248.98.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-15T06:21:08" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c478f"), "ip" : "111.243.254.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-11T00:54:30" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c4790"), "ip" : "111.248.102.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-14T04:10:31" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58784108b0925e52ec4c4791"), "ip" : "36.229.236.0", "history" : [ { "aging_type" : "static", "from" : "dragonresearchgroup.org", "threat" : "Scanners", "updated_time" : "2016-05-13T22:51:34" } ], "updated_time" : "2017-01-13T10:52:56" }
```

Suppose I want to retrieve "history" value whose "ip" value is "61.228.93.0", and then extend `[{'aging_type':static,'updated_time':2017-1-13T10:55:22}]` to that list value, then update that "history" value with the extended list, what am I supposed to do?
  I've tried `db.collection.find({"ip":'ip'})['history']` and `db.collection.find({"ip":'ip'},{'history':1})` but it seems no help..
  I'd be grateful if someone kind could help me with this problem

Comment: try this `db.collection.find( { ip: "61.228.93.0" } )` to get values whose ip is `61.228.93.0`

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the history value for a document by IP:

```
db.collection.find_one({'ip': '61.228.93.0'})['history']
```

To add to the history array:

```
result = db.collection.update_one(
    {'ip': '61.228.93.0'},
    {'$push': {'history': {'aging_type': 'static',
                           'updated_time': '2017-1-13T10:55:22'}}})

print(result.raw_result)
```

This prints:

```
{'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1.0, u'n': 1}
```

To add to the history array and get the updated document in a single command:

```
from pymongo import ReturnDocument
result = db.collection.find_one_and_update(
    {'ip': '61.228.93.0'},
    {'$push': {'history': {'aging_type': 'static',
                           'updated_time': '2017-1-13T10:55:22'}}},
    return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)

print(result)
```